# Как вызвать метод с параметром ActionEvent в другом методе?

Tags: java, javafx

Есть метод:

```
public void Process (ActionEvent event){
   String num = ((Button)event.getSource()).getText();
   output.setText(output.getText()+num); // output это название TextField
}
```

Хочу вызвать метод Process в методе processNum:

```
void processNum(){
   Process(Какой параметр сюда вставлять?);
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Это не так-то просто сделать, поскольку события возникают в процессе каких-то действий пользователя и метод с параметром `ActionEvent` зарегистирован как обработчик такого события.

Незачем создавать еще один метод, для обработки события, которое не поступает в метод обработки событий.